# Installing Subclipse, M2Eclipse, and M2Eclipse Extras into Eclipse Helios from Command Line?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to automate the install process for OpenMRS developers 
http://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Step+by+Step+Installation+for+Developers

I have found a helpful reference here:
http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html

And have created a command line:
./eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x,http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/,http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras/ -installIU org.maven.ide.eclipse,org.maven.ide.eclipse.scm,org.maven.ide.eclipse.subclipse,org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter,org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl,org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core

That *seems* to mirror my Eclipse install.

However, on further investigation, it seems that certain things are not installed. Notably, all *features* related to the application seem completely missing under the features/ folder.

Is there a good way to *see a list of all installable units* in Eclipse?

The logs seem to record *features*, there is a bundles.list file that record *bundles = plugins*,
but where can I see a log of installable units in Eclipse?

Thank you
Misha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was very helpfully answered by the equinox developers:
http://old.nabble.com/List-of-installable-units-or-log---using-p2-director-to-automate-Subclipse%2C-M2eclipse%2C-and-M2eclipse-Extra-for-OpenMRS-developers-ts29693317.html

A complete list of all the IUs that have been installed is available in the most recent profile file located in /p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry//

In order to facilitate things for you users, you may want to create one IU that refers to all the elements you need.
This way your end user only has one thing to install

Thank you again

Misha